# Convert Class Component to Function Component - Expand/Collapse Header Depending on Scroll Position

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

My goal is to turn [this](https://dev.to/guimg/hide-menu-when-scrolling-in-reactjs-47bj) class component into a function component.

The issue, however, with my Functional Component Implementation is that when I scroll up, the header is instantly expanded. I only want the header visible if the page is at the absolute top.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import classnames from "classnames";

import "./header.styles.scss";

const Header = () => {
  const [isHidden, setIsHidden] = useState(0);

  const [prevScrollPos, setPrevScollPos] = useState(window.pageYOffset);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleScrollChange() {
      setIsHidden(prevScrollPos < window.pageYOffset);
      setPrevScollPos(window.pageYOffset);
    }
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScrollChange);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScrollChange);
    };
  });

  return (
    <div
      className={classnames("header", {
        "header-hidden": isHidden,
      })}
    >
      <div className="logo-container">A & A Solutions</div>
      <div className="options">
        <div className="option">Option 1</div>
        <div className="option">Option 2</div>
        <div className="option">Option 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: If you only want to let the header visible if the page is at the absolute top, i think you can try `setIsHidden(window.pageYOffset !== 0)`

Comment: You should get rid of that second state declaration, you are changing that state with every scroll, that is very bad performance wise and it could cause some side effects. 
You should use refs if you want to check that kind of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the `window.scrollY` property and see if it is at 0. This means the top of the window's scrollbar's Y-axis at the very top.

```
function handleScrollChange() {
  setIsHidden(window.scrollY !== 0);
}
```

As a side note, I don't think you should add and clean up your event listeners every time a side effect occurs. You could probably look into using the `[]` dependency for your `useEffect` since you can omit the checking of `prevScrollPos`

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and
> unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This
> tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props
> or state, so it never needs to re-run.

Comment: can the down voter explain what needs to be improved in my post?

Comment: When I remove the listener it no longer functions.

Comment: you're not suppose to remove the listener. I suggested to only initialize it when the component mounts and clean it when the component unmounts

Comment: Ok, so just add the second bracket as another paramater and the function only runs once. ok, thank you!

Comment: I've written a [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-sanderson-9h9h7?file=/src/Header.js) which could clarify my suggestion. I've put comments in the code